# Solve $\arg\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} I_C(x) + \alpha \sum_i \left\|y_i -x \right\|_2^2$, where $I_C(x)$: indicator function; set $C$: norm 2 ball

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have a problem on hand that I am not sure how to handle it. Can you please help/guide me to solve this optimization problem?

\begin{align}
\arg\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} I_C(x) + \alpha \sum_i \left\|y_i -x \right\|_2^2 \ ,
\end{align}
where $I_C(x)$ is an [indicator or characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(convex_analysis)) and the set $C$ can be a norm-2 ball, i.e., $C = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \left\|x - c \right\|_2^2 \leq r\right\}$, $y_i, c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are given, and $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

**My partial attempt**:

The above problem can be rewritten as
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:weighted_projection_problem_definition_3}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}} 
& & \alpha \sum_i \left\|y_i -x \right\|_2^2 \\
& \text{subject to}
& &  \left\|x - c \right\|_2^2 \leq r \ ,\\
%&&& X \succeq 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Right?

If yes, then I think it is possible to solve in the closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's complete the square: $\| y_i - x \|^2 = \|y_i\|^2 - 2 \langle y_i, x \rangle + \|x\|^2$, so
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N \|y_i - x \|^2 &= -2 \left \langle \sum_{i=1}^N y_i, x \right\rangle + N \|x\|^2 + \ldots \\
&=N \left(-2 \left \langle \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N y_i, x \right\rangle  + \|x\|^2 \right) + \ldots \\
&= N \left\|x - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N y_i \right\|^2 + \ldots
\end{align}
where the ellipses ($\ldots$) indicate terms that do not depend on $x$. It follows that
\begin{align}
\arg\min_x \, I_C(x) + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^N \|y_i - x \|^2&=
\arg\min_x I_C(x) + \alpha N \left\|x - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N y_i \right\|^2 \\
&= \text{projection of } \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N y_i \text{ onto } C.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much. I was thinking that it should boil down to projection problem...